# How to color diacritical marks?

Tags: color, characters, accents

I would like to have the diacritical marks stand out visually by being colored differently. For example, can I have â in which the circumflex is in red, and the 'a' is in black? When I use `\textcolor{...}` for the diacritical mark, it is not placed correctly over (or under) the letter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main problem is when you use a `T1` encoded font, in which accented chars are no longer composed by overimposing the diacritic on a "unaccented" char, but instead they are a new glyph which includes the diacritic as part of its design.

For this case, the only solution I can imagine is a hack: first write the accented char in red, then backtrace and draw in black the same char but without accent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\trick#1#2{\textcolor{red}{#1}\llap{#2}}

\begin{document}
a \trick{â}{a} â
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I tried this with latex on Ubuntu and just got two regular a's with no accent or color.

Comment: @JosephGarvin Sounds like a encoding issue. Instead of `â`, try writing `\^a`. Also, it could be a font problem; you can try using `\usepackage{lmodern}` instead of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newbox\accentboxa
\newbox\accentboxb

\newcommand{\redhat}[1]{\setbox\accentboxa=\hbox{\^#1}%
\setbox\accentboxb=\hbox{\^{}}\leavevmode
\kern\dimexpr(\wd\accentboxa-\wd\accentboxb)/2\relax
{\color{red}%
\raise\dimexpr\ht\accentboxa-\ht\accentboxb\relax\copy\accentboxb}%
\kern-\dimexpr(\wd\accentboxa+\wd\accentboxb)/2\relax #1}

\begin{document}

\^a\redhat{a}\^a

\^A\redhat{A}\^A

\end{document}
```

[image]